# Adding observers

Tags: ios, swift

I've added observers like the below

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(handleCourseCompleted(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name ("com.course.completed"), object: nil)
```

Is this how to remove them

```
deinit {
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your app doesn't run on iOS 8 or earlier, there is no need to remove the observer at all. The notification center has an ARC-weak reference to it, and nothing bad will happen after `self` goes out of existence.

Comment: I am seeing that the observer function is being called more than once

Comment: Then that is what you should have asked about. It's probably because the `addObserver` method is being called more than once, but you'd have to give a _lot_ more information in order to track that down. Is the view controller leaking? If so, the cause is not shown in your question. The question you ask is the question that gets answered...